# how to get todays feeds using graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using graph api explorer to test my results.
I tried getting todays posts by the below query

```
1061547241/feed?fields=object_id&since=1378122100&limit=100
```

I am confused with the since parameter. some one help get todays posts using since parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets take a look at the documentation for graph api:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/pagination/#timepaging

According to that it uses http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php function to convert the "since" parameter. So if you want to get it for today you can do something like:

```
1061547241/feed?fields=object_id&since=today
```

This would give you feed since start of the day i.e. 00:00:00.

For more details on formats you search for datetime.formats in php, doesn't allow me to post more than 2 links.

Comment: but itseems like taking yesterdays posts too. it is working on greenwich time may be

Comment: Yes it seems to be taking time in UTC time zone. In that case you should just convert the start of the day in your desired time zone to UTC and use it in since.